# updating child entity in parent entity gives duplicate violation key error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have below classes spacetype and mastersection  which is having below structure

```
public class SpaceType
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MasterSection")]
    public string MasterSectionName { get; set; }
    public virtual MasterSection MasterSection { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("LibrarySpaceTypeCategory")]
    public Guid? LibrarySpaceTypeCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual LibrarySpaceTypeCategory LibrarySpaceTypeCategory { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public MechanicalData MechanicalData { get; set; }
}

public class MasterSection
{
    [Key, GraphQLNonNullType]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<SectionEmployee> SectionOwners { get; set; } = new List<SectionEmployee>();

    [ForeignKey("ParentMasterSection"), GraphQLIgnore]
    public string ParentMasterSectionName { get; set; }
    public virtual MasterSection ParentMasterSection { get; set; }
}
```

and i am trying to update mastersection object for all spacetypes like as below

```
        var spaceTypes = ctx.SpaceTypes.ToList();
        foreach(var spacetype in spaceTypes)
        {
            spacetype.MasterSection = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Space Type"];
        }
        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

and below is the data that I am getting from `masterSectionMappedLibrary["Space Type"]`

[image]

and getting an error here `ctx.SaveChanges();` like `Duplicate key violates unique constraint on PK_Mastersections`.

Could any one please let me know where i am doing wrong and i am using EF core with postgreSQL.

Many thanks in advance

Update:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `spacetype.MasterSectionName = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Space Type"].Name ;`. I'm afraid that EF Core is changing the `MasterSection  entity` itself, instead of foreign key fo your `SpaceType` model.

Comment: I believe this way will work but when i am going to serialize the master section in spacetype it is coming as null, and to avoid that i am assigning mastersection during ef migration with the code  listed in that question , `How to avoid that not to change the master section entity just the foreignKey for your spacetype`

Comment: Well, then try to `.Include()` your `master section` before serialization, I think that could possibly work.

Comment: yeah that is fine but i need to modify(need to take care on  not  to be null for mastersection object) the already existing data in db that is why i am doing this in migration

Comment: What I mean is that use `MasterSectionName` for updating the db, then fetch the updated data with included correct values and then serialize it.

Comment: I just updated the question with the image where i am getting the null values for mastersection with this code `var spaceTypes = ctx.SpaceTypes.ToList();
            foreach(var spacetype in spaceTypes)
            {
                spacetype.MasterSectionName = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Space Type"].Name;
                ctx.Entry(spacetype).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }           
            ctx.SaveChanges();`

Comment: i don't know where i am doing wrong i am updating mastersection object with proper values or is there any other way alternative to what i am doing above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var spaceTypes = ctx.SpaceTypes.ToList();
foreach(var spacetype in spaceTypes)
{
   spacetype.MasterSectionName = masterSectionMappedLibrary["Space Type"].Name;
}
ctx.UpdateRange(spaceTypes);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

After you save the updated value to db, try to retrieve it again

```
var spaceTypesUpdated = ctx.SpaceTypes
                        .Include("MasterSection.ParentMasterSection")
                        .Include("SectionOwners")
                        .ToList();
// serialize spaceTypesUpdated to json
```